# VStack height varying with embedded WaveFormView, how to stabilize it?

Tags: swift, swiftui, waveform

Trying to make a WaveFormView for the Guitar Tuner I am designing.

```
struct WaveFormView: View {
  @State private var phase = 0.0
  let amplitude: Double
  let frequency: Double
  let waveColor: Color
  let echoes: Double
  
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      ForEach(0..<5) { i in
        Wave(amplitude: amplitude, frequency: frequency, phase: self.phase)
          .stroke(waveColor.opacity((Double(i)/abs(echoes))), lineWidth: 2)
          .offset(y: -CGFloat(i) * CGFloat(echoes))
      }
      .mask {
        LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.clear, .white, . clear]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)
      }
      .onAppear {
        withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 1).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {
          self.phase = .pi * 2
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I put this inside a VStack, this will force the height of the VStack to be variable. It pulses with the same period of the phase animation in the WaveFormView.

Here's the ContentView:

```
struct TunerView: View {
  @StateObject var controller = PitchData()
  var pitchEngine = PitchEngine()
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Spacer()
      Text(controller.pitchString)     // Note letter
        .font(.system(size: 100))
      Spacer()

      ZStack{                                // Here are the waves 
        WaveFormView(amplitude: 30,
                     frequency: controller.pitchFrequency,
                     waveColor: controller.isTuned ? .blue : .red,
                     echoes: controller.offsetCents)
        WaveFormView(amplitude: 30,
                     frequency: controller.closestOffsetFrequency,
                     waveColor: controller.isTuned ? .blue : .red,
                     echoes: 1)                  
        .frame(height: 400)
        .border(.blue)
        .onAppear { startPitchEngine() }
      } 
    }
    .border(.red)
  }
```

BUT....
The most baffling thing is this: if I rotate the device landscape, then back portrait, the height of the VStack becomes stabilises to the value I want (full screen). No more bug.

Have posted a short video on my GitHub, please feel free to take a look.
https://github.com/Salubrejoe/Tuner/blob/main/RPReplay_Final1685114259.MOV

Thanks in advance for any help!

I thought it might be the WFView itself, but the behaviour appears only after I embed it in a Stack.

If I do that and then use the spacer to push down the view, the graph gets indeed push down, but any other content overlayed on the original Stack keeps animating.

Comment: The issue is most likely starting your animation in `.onAppear()`. The issue with that is `.onAppear()` kicks off before the view is on the screen. At the time `.onAppear()` fires, the sizes of the views are not set, so the animation does not have the size it needs to properly animate. If I am correct, the solution is simple: don't start the animation in `.onAppear` or start it with a delay with `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline:)`. I would test it, but you didn't post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you so much, indeed that was the issue. 
(Sorry for the MRE, first post ever here).

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, by Yrb:

> "The issue is most likely starting your animation in `.onAppear()`. The issue with that is `.onAppear()` kicks off before the view is on the screen. At the time `.onAppear()` fires, the sizes of the views are not set, so the animation does not have the size it needs to properly animate. If I am correct, the solution is simple: don't start the animation in `.onAppear` or start it with a delay with `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline:)`. I would test it, but you didn't post a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)."